# Updating nested list without AsNoTracking

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Simplified model:

```
Profile {Guid Id, string Name, List<Property> Properties}
Property {Guid Id, string Name, List<Type> Types}
Type {Guid Id, string Key, string Value}
```

DbContext:

```
{
     public DbSet<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
}
```

I didn't include `Properties` and `Types` in the DbContext so I used the ModelBuilder:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Property>().HasMany<Type>();
```

In the Update service:

```
public async Task<Response> Update([FromBody] Profile profile)
{
var entity = await _context.Profiles
    .Include(x => x.Properties)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.Types)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == profile.Id);

foreach (var prop in profile.Properties)
{
    var existingProp = entity.Properties.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == prop.Id);
    //Update
    if (existingProp != null)
    {
        var entry = _context.Entry(existingProp);
        entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        existingProp.ChargeFrom(prop);//maps the new values to the db entity
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
}
```

But the above code throws this exception at `SaveChanges`:

> The instance of entity type 'Type' cannot be tracked because another
> instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked.
> When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance
> with a given key value is attached. Consider using
> 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the
> conflicting key values.

I marked the `Types` entity `AsNoTracking`:

```
.ThenInclude(x => x.Types).AsNoTracking()
```

and the problem is solved, but I don't know why this exception is thrown, some other thread mentions that the DbContext might be used by another process, and might be registered as Singleton, but in my case, it's registered as scoped.

Comment: Get rid of the useless `entry` variable and `entry.State` modification and problem solved. `existingProp` is already tracked by EF, you **don't** have to manually add it to be tracked

Comment: The `Value` property is not updated without it, or the parent object (`entity`) should be `Modified`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I marked the Types entity AsNoTracking:
> `.ThenInclude(x => x.Types).AsNoTracking()`
> and the problem is solved, but I don't know why this exception is thrown

The reason for the error will be because this line:

```
existingProp.ChargeFrom(prop);//maps the new values to the db entity
```

... will be attempting to copy the untracked Types from `prop` into `existingProp`.  Using `AsNoTracking` will remove the exception but it will most likely be resulting in a duplication of data on `SaveChanges` where `Type` would be set up with an Identity key or duplicate row exceptions. If you received no exception I would be checking the Types collection to see if there are duplicate rows appearing there.

When copying data across from an untracked entity to a tracked entity, you will want to ensure that only values, and not references, are copied across. Copying an untracked reference across, EF will treat that as a new entity by default. Even if you force its state over to `Modified`, the DbContext could already be tracking an entity with that ID.

If Property.Types is a collection of references, such as an association to a lookup, and these could change where associations are added and removed, then to apply changes you need to load the associated types from the database then use that to remove associations that are no longer valid and add ones that aren't currently associated.

For example: given a Property (PropertyA) with Types (Type1) and (Type2), if we edit that to have (Type1) and (Type3) we need to fetch Type1 & Type3 from the DbContext (tracked) then compare against the tracked PropertyA to determine to remove Type2 and add Type3

```
var entity = await _context.Profiles
    .Include(x => x.Properties)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.Types)
    .SingleAsync(x => x.Id == profile.Id);

// Get the IDs for all Types we want to associate... In the above example this would
// ask for Type1 and Type3 if only the one property. We get a Distinct list because
// multiple properties might reference the same TypeId(s).
var existingTypeIds = profile.Properties
    .SelectMany(x => x.Types.Select(t => t.Id))
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();

// Load references to all Types that will be needed. Where associating new types, these will be referenced.
var existingTypes = _context.Types
    .Where(x => existingTypeIds.Contains(x.Id))
    .ToList();

foreach (var prop in profile.Properties)
{   
    existingProp = entity.Properties.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == prop.Id);
    if (existingProp == null)
        continue;

    var updatedTypeIds = prop.Types.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
    var existingTypeIds = existingProp.Types.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

    var addedTypeIds = updatedTypeIds.Except(existingTypeIds).ToList();
    var removedTypeIds = existingTypeIds.Except(updatedTypeIds).ToList();

    var addedTypes = existingTypes
        .Where(x => addedTypeIds.Contains(x.Id))
        .ToList();
    var removedTypes = existingProp.Types
        .Where(x => removedTypeIds.Contains(x.Id))
        .ToList();

    foreach(var removedType in removedTypes)
        existingProp.Types.Remove(removedType);

    foreach(var addedType in addedTypes)
        existingProp.Types.Add(addedType);

}
```

If instead the type is a child row that contains properties that can be updated then these values should be copied across between the updated data and the existing data state. This adds a considerable amount of work, though tools like AutoMapper can be configured to help. You still need to manage cases where Types can be added, removed, or have contents changed. That would apply to Properties as well, as your example only handles cases where a property is updated, not potentially added or removed.

Ultimately it can be beneficial to try and structure update scenarios to be as atomic as possible to avoid an update that is going to make changes to an entire object graph of entities, properties, and types but rather one update for just entity values, one for property values, and one for a single type update. This would apply also to adding a property, adding a type, removing a property, removing a type. While it may look like more code to break up operations like this, it keeps them very simple and straight forward rather than one big, complex method trying to compare the before and after to figure out what to add, remove, and update.  Bugs hide in complex code, not simple methods. :)

When editing an object graph you should also avoid calling `SaveChanges` more than once. Instead of calling it within the loop of properties it should be done once when the loop is completed. The reason for this is that something like an exception on one of the properties would result in an incomplete/invalid data state being persisted. If you have 4 properties in the object being saved, and the 3rd one fails with an exception for any reason, the first 2 will be updated with the last two not persisting. Generally within an update operation, the update should follow an "all or nothing" approach to persistence.

Hopefully that helps explain the behavior you are seeing and gives you something to consider moving forward.

Comment: Thanks for that complete answer, actually I couldn't expect to go that complex!
I asked for the update as I was having problems with it. Can I update your answer with full code (Property (add/ remove/ update), Types(add/ remove/ update) )?